# How to get variable from a Global service in ionic?

Tags: typescript

I am trying to create an app in ionic but facing some issues. I tried to access a variable from a global service when it being imported to another page. For instance, I have the following `Global service (backend)`:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
/*
  Generated class for the BackendProvider provider.
*/
@Injectable()
export class BackendProvider {

  
}

export class  globalUrl{
  public globalUrl: "http://192.168.0.6:81/EBSWebApi/";

}
```

In my user service I imported it this way:

```
import {globalUrl} from "../backend/backend";

And trying to access the **globalUrl** I did this:

export class UserProvider {

  private url = globalUrl + "/api/getUsers";

}
```

Please, how can I do this right?

Answer (score 0):

You want to export a constant not a class if your aim is just to have a global object full of key value pairs. This is already done for you in your src/environments/environments.ts file, which should be used for this kind of thing.

```
export const environment = {
   baseUrl = 'https://www.test.com'
}
```

In your ts:

```
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment'

...


const myUrl = environment.baseUrl + '/parameters'
```